# LinkingObjects in Realm has no code completion for initialiser (XCode 12, Swift 5)

Tags: swift, xcode, realm, initializer, linkingobjects

When trying to initialise LinkingObjects in Realm, there is no code completion appearing in XCode. Even after typing first external parameter and its value, there is no seems to appear.

Line 16 is how it should be initialise according to Realm Docs.

[image]

Comment: I duplicated the issue. The LinkingObjects will work correctly you just have to manually type it in as the code completion is broken. There's a [git](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/6970) bug report.

Comment: Thanks for the notice. I was trying to find the solution and there is no way of doing it.

Comment: Keep in mind that LinkingObjects works correctly, it's just not autocompleting because the function definition was changed when they added @frozen objects (around v10 or so).

Comment: Yeah i think so too